# Import tree dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, nested-sets

Working with laravel-nested sets Baum's package and try to import tree into mysql database. Import data:

```
1. FirstLevelWord1 - SecondLevelWord1 - ThirdLevelWord1 - FourthLevelWord1
2. FirstLevelWord1 - SecondLevelWord1 - ThirdLevelWord1 - FourthLevelWord2
3. FirstLevelWord1 - SecondLevelWord1 - ThirdLevelWord1 - FourthLevelWord3
```

I need to update the same words instead write duplicates in database. But now i can do this only with first-level word - don't know how to update same words at the second and subsequent levels dynamically.

Import method

```
foreach ($words as $value){
  $c = explode("-", $value);                         
  $root = Chain::firstOrCreate(['cWord' => $c[0]]); 

   for ($i = 1; $i < count($c) ; $i++) {    
      $prevChild = null;
      if (Chain::where('cWord', $c[$i])->first()){  
         $prevChild = Chain::where('cWord', $c[$i-1])->first(); 
      }

      $child = Chain::create(['cWord' => $c[$i]]);

      if($i == 1){
        $child->makeChildOf($root);
      } else {
        $child->makeChildOf(
        $root->getDescendants()[count($root->getDescendants())-1]);
      }
   }

   $node = Chain::where('cWord', '=', $c[0])->first();
}
```

Instead this structure

[image]

I get this

[image]

As you see, words on second and third level are duplicate. Any ideas how i can fix this?

Comment: You might want to consider using English values if you want to reach more people for help

Comment: Yep, forgot about this. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your Chain class works so I did this using associative arrays. You will have to alter this to work with your Chain class.

```
$words = [
    "бить - разбить - разбивать - разбивание",
    "бить - разбить - разбивать - разбиватель",
    "бить - разбить - разбивать - разбивка",
];

$structure = [];

function fill(array $structure, string $x, ...$xs): array {
    if (!isset($structure[$x])) {
        $structure[$x] = [];
    }

    if ($xs) {
        $structure[$x] = fill($structure[$x], ...$xs);
    }

    return $structure;
}

foreach ($words as $value) {
    $c = explode(" - ", $value);

    $structure = fill($structure, ...$c);
}

print_r($structure);
```

Edit: I added some code so this can be used with the [buildtree](https://github.com/etrepat/baum#seedingmass-assignment) method. I'm sure there is a way Baum can be integrated with the above function to simplify all of this.

```
function createBaumTree(array $structure): array
{
    $baumTree = [];

    foreach ($structure as $key => $value) {
        if ($value) {
            $baumTree[] = [
                'name' => $key,
                'children' => createBaumTree($value),
            ];
            continue;
        }

        $baumTree[] = ['name' => $key];
    }

    return $baumTree;
}

$baumTree = createBaumTree($structure);

print_r($baumTree);
```

Comment: I need to use the Baum's package tools to index the children that are added dynamically

Comment: Okay, now I see I missed the Baum's part of the question. I might be able to use the [maketree](https://github.com/etrepat/baum#seedingmass-assignment) function to get this to work for you.